# Is there an elegant way for handling tailwind responsive?

Tags: responsive, tailwind-css

Rookie in tailwind, been doing custom CSS media query. I'm **trying to understand if there's any elegant way to handle such code** for different screen sizes.

Given that I have different screen sizes to handle, in this case more columns will be added depending on the screen size. Currently, Im assigning different class values to the individual sizes.

Imagine if I have more visuals to handle different screen sizes, how can I do it more elegantly? or this is what I should expect?

```
<div
          class="grid grid-cols-7 
        qs:bg-pink-400 qs:grid-cols-3
        sm:bg-blue-400 sm:grid-cols-4
        md:bg-violet-600 md:grid-cols-5   
        lg:bg-lime-400 lg:grid-cols-6  
        xl:bg-red-400"
        >
          <h1 className="text-red-100 font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
          <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
          <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
          <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
          <h1 className="text-6xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
          <h1 className="text-7xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
        </div>
```

FYI,
Using `"tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"`, and im setting my screens px as follow.

```
screens: {
      qs: { max: "479px" },
      sm: { min: "480px" },
      md: { min: "768px" },
      lg: { min: "976px" },
      xl: { min: "1440px" },
    },
```

Comment: This is expected unless you're using Frontend frameworks with something like WindiCSS or UnoCSS or CDN. I personally would get rid off `qs` breakpoint as Tailwind is mobile-first and such variant is pointless in my opinion.

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka thanks for the response. Regards to the `qs`, you mean to suggest keep `sm` as the smallest.. and handle only rest of the screen sizes right? So by default.. my design must always default in Mobile First, follow by Tablet, Laptop, etc.

Comment: In your case `grid sm:hidden` means grid before 480px, hidden after which the same as `qs:grid sm:hidden`. Any non-variant utilities means from mobile to laptop etc unless overriden. In this example both `grid-cols-7` and `qs:grid-cols-3` should be applied on mobile which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by the custom dimensions you are using for your `screens` object as it doesn't seem to adhere to the typical dimensions you would see for a monitor. Tailwind's [responsive design](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) handles many cases by default as you can [see at the Tailwind playground I created](https://play.tailwindcss.com/MxXGTOkZyd) that uses your styling but doesn't require the screen object. It seems as though your primary concern may be mobile devices which do not meet these responsive dimensions. In those cases **you should not use sizing like this.** The [Working mobile-first](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#working-mobile-first) section of the Tailwind documentation specifically covers cases like this:

```
Where this approach surprises people most often is that to style something for mobile, you need to use the unprefixed version of a utility, not the sm: prefixed version. Don’t think of sm: as meaning “on small screens”, think of it as “at the small breakpoint“.
```

If you are designing for mobile devices you shouldn't do this:

```html
<!-- This will only center text on screens 640px and wider, not on small screens -->
<div class="sm:text-center"></div>
```

but this:

```html
<!-- This will center text on mobile, and left align it on screens 640px and wider -->
<div class="text-center sm:text-left"></div>
```

By taking advantage of `max-*` you can then create something like [this](https://play.tailwindcss.com/VibpmvKaKA?size=440x720). Now I have an additional color any time the size is under the 640px size for `sm` it's a teal color instead of the pink for anything between 640 and 768.

So yes what you want to achieve is doable but you should try to work within Tailwind unless you absolutely must support those non-standard screen sizes.

Comment: The dimension set was just an example for myself to explore Tailwind. Yup, understand you're saying by default Tailwind is supporting as a mobile first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for now, there is no more elegant approach other than the above mentioned code.

But, I would suggest you to minimize the code slightly by considering the fact, `tailwind-css` uses `mobile-first breakpoint system`. so any screen less than tablet as `base class` , use `md:` for tablet and `lg:` for laptop and `xl:` for monitor screen and above.

Therefore you could modify your code to :

```
<div
   class="grid grid-cols-4 bg-green-400       <-- base class for any screen less than tablet
      md:bg-violet-600 md:grid-cols-5         <-- tablet screen
      lg:bg-lime-400 lg:grid-cols-6           <-- laptop screen
      xl:bg-red-400 xl:grid-cols-7">          <-- monitor and above
```

Note: if the idea of breakpoints such as `qs`,`sm`,`md`,`lg`,`xl` seems confusing. Use much simpler understandable version.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'mobile': '480px',
      // => @media (min-width: 480px) { ... }

      'tablet': '640px',
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

      'laptop': '1024px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

      'desktop': '1280px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }
    },
  }
}
```

Further use this link https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

Comment: I don't understand your example, why is your base using `grids-cols-7` for base? If you're talking about mobile first concept. In this case, should it be `grids-cols-4` as base, then for you set another `xl: grids-cols-7`.

Comment: My bad. I was focused on the approach rather not on details | Edit has been made. please follow up

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this if there needs to be a lot of elements:

```
const style = {a:`css here`, b:``, etc }



/*Page*/


<Component/div className={style.a/b/etc}> Hello</div>
```